# How to pass the props to Svelte component from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have the default page of my webapp which redirects to different components, something like as follows:

```
<script>
  import page from "page";
  import Form from "./Form.svelte";
  import Dashboard from "./Dashboard.svelte";

  let content = "";
  page.base("/");
  page("", function() {
    content = Form;
  });
  page("dashboard", function() {
    content = Dashboard;
  });
  page({
    hashbang: true
  });
</script>
```

Now, if I want to pass some props in say, Dashboard page from here, how can I do that? I tried following but it didn't work.

```
content = new Dashboard({
    props: {
        answer: 42
    }
});
```

Comment: Can't you use [Sapper](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sapper+svelte&t=ffab&atb=v169-1&ia=software)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the docs for [`<svelte:component>`](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_component). To pass down arbitrary props you can use an attribute spread:

```html
<svelte:component this={content} {...props}/>
```

Here's a live example: https://svelte.dev/repl/74593f36569a4c268d8a6ab277db34b5?version=3.12.1

Here's an official example (currently doesn't demonstrate passing down props): https://svelte.dev/examples#svelte-component